# How do I change the localhost:8500 to something else in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, localhost, coldfusion-9, host

I have set up ColdFusion 9, as this is an old system, and have to change the host path. All of the code is already there, but it does not work because the path is wrong and it keeps redirecting.

The current default path is `localhost:8500`,  but I need it to redirect to `localhost:8500/newdir/`.  I thought by changing my `systems32\drivers\etc\hosts` file this would work, but it hasn't.

Windows with internal server for ColdFusion9, Apache.

Would like to redirect the host.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Mappings in the Server Settings section of the ColdFusion Administration.

Add a Mapping with `/` as the Logical Path and the physical path of `/newdir` as the Directory Path.

Comment: Thanks. We changed our direction so doing something different but thank you.